# Will hive dynamic partitioning update all partitions?

Tags: hive

I want to use the hive dynamic partitioning to overwrite a partitioned table "page_view":

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE page_view PARTITION(date)
   SELECT pvs.viewTime FROM page_view_stg pvs
```

My question is : If the table "page_view_stg" only has the data of "date=2017-01-01", but the dest table "page_view" has a partition "date=2017-01-02". So after running this query, will the partition "date=2017-01-02" get dropped or not? If not, how should I handle this case using dynamic partitioning?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Query with dynamic partitioning will overwrite only partitions existing in the source dataset. In your case `partition "date=2017-01-02"` will remain unchanged if the the source table does not contain such date. If you want to drop it, the fastest method is to execute `alter table drop partition` statement because this is the metadata operation. You select partitions from target table which do not exist in the source and generate drop statements using shell. Or insert into new table, drop old target, then rename.